# Update width after new element added

Tags: xamarin.ios, resize, monotouch.dialog

I have a simple section with a short caption = "A" in the first EntryElement. So the first element caption width is very small.

Then, I have to add new elements programmatically. The new elements that I have to add have captions larger than the first one (like  "AAAA"). As result, the new captions columns are smaller than the new captions text so the caption and the entry are overlapped.

There is a method in order to update the entire section to fit all new captions in there?

Comment: I'm unsure what you want to achieve. Can you clarify it by adding code and/or screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

It's quick and dirty, but why not just add

```
"A".PadRight(100)
```

to the first EntryElement caption?